# Can't call parent div without animating children too

Tags: jquery, hover, nested, parent-child

I've searched, expecting this to be common and an easy fix but none of the solutions I found worked in this situation.

I am a vendor so I can't alter the clients html to use ULs. The goal is to have the content div's opacity fade on hover. What is happening is, the img and text within that parent div are also fading on hover. I can't use .css because it is an abrupt change and I don't believe duration can be set.

css

```
 .content {
 position:relative;
width:126px;
height:138px;
background: #3C3C3C;
}
```

html

```
<div class="content">
<img class="band_im" rel="26" src="" />
<div>Contractor</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$("div.content").hover(function() {
       // attempted, no luck $("img.badge_ico").css({opacity: "1"});*
 $("div.content").stop().animate({opacity: "0.5"}, '500');
    },
    function() {
           // attempted, no luck  $(".badge_ico").css({opacity: "1"});
      $("div.content").stop().animate({opacity: "1"}, '800');
    });
```

Comment: That is how opacity just works...

Comment: Why you need to fade parent container? Looks like you want to fade background image or something. Please show more your HTML markup.

Comment: i want to fade the background color that is defined in the container. I tried animating the backgroundColor to a darker color and it wasn't responding for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything in the div that should get dimmed as well, or just the div? If you are going for a color change affect, I would suggest changing the background color on the div itself rather than changing its opacity (there are plugins to animate color changes).

If there are other contents in the div you want to dim, the only way to go about it would be to move the things you don't want dim out of the div, probably needing to set absolute positions as well, before animating the opacity. Difficult and hacky, but possible.

Comment: I only want to dim the background color of the content div. Right now, the img and text within that container are also dimming. And this all must be self-contained, no plugins allowed.

Comment: In that case, your best bet would probably be to change the color one step at a time on a regular interval. The quick and dirty way might be to do setTimeout(function(){$("div.content").style("background-color":"#EEE"},50); repeat decreasing the color and increasing the timeout. Better way is to loop at a regular interval and change the color value programatically depending on what color you want it to be.